# Spark triggering partitioning automatically

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark, distributed-computing

I am running an EMR cluster with following configuration:
1 master, 4 slaves. Total executor count: 11, each executor has 5 cores and 34GB memory. The dynamical allocation is set to True.

My pyspark workflow has following steps:

> 1. Read in 50 csv files with a combined total of 100,000 lines from S3
>      into a spark dataframe(df). Running df.rdd.getNumPartitions() returns
>      50 partitions.
> 2. Using df.repartition(1000), I repartition this dataframe into 1000 partitions.
> 3. Using a pandas UDF function, I run some operation on this dataframe and assign the result to another dataframe (result_df). This dataframe
>      has an additional string column compared to df.
> 4. I now run result_df.write.format("parquet").save(s3_path_dest, mode="overwrite") to save the result to an S3 location. At this point,
>      I see that I get 2 'save' stages in the spark web UI. The first stage
>      has 50 tasks indicating there are 50 partitions while the second stage
>      has 1000 tasks corresponding to 1000 partitions.
> 5. I then run another pandas UDF function on the above dataframe (result_df) which returns 2 more columns in addition to the older 2
>      columns and save the resulting df to an S3 location as was done in
>      step 4. I now see that there are again 2 stages: First stage has only
>      5 tasks while second has 1000 tasks.

Question 1: Why did this 'automatic' repartitioning happen? (5 partitions)

Question 2: Why is this process split into 2 stages where each stage operates on different partition count? I expect a single stage working on 1000 tasks/partitions.

Question 3: In the spark UI SQL tab, I see that the last step starts with a 'FileScan csv' step. Does it mean that when I execute my last step, the entire workflow gets executed from starting again? I do not expect this since I had already triggered an intermediate save action (step 4) which should execute the DAG upto that point and have no need to recompute the results that might be needed in the future steps.

Thanks in advance for your help.